# IF condition with getdate() in sybase

Tags: sql, if-statement, sybase

I have a requirement where if

`getdate()`

returns time between midnight 12 to 2 AM, I should consider Date of previous day. How to frame this in a select query ?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Comment: I am trying current_time() as follows -
`where tdate >= CASE WHEN current_time() >= "00:00:00.001 AM" and  current_time() <= "00:01:59.999 AM" THEN datediff(dd, -1, getdate()) ELSE getdate()`

I am not familiar with the syntax for it ,its failing.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is to subtract two hours from the date and do the comparison.  For instance:

```
where col_date < convert(date, dateadd(hour, -2, getdate()))
```